# Query to find all users with a particular role in parse api

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, role

I am working with pars javascript api. What i am trying to do is, retrieving all users of a particular role.
I used this code to do it.

```
var query = (new Parse.Query(Parse.Role));
query.equalTo("name", "admin");
query.first({ success: function(role) {
  role.relation('users').query().find({success: function(users) {
  }});
}});
```

The problem is that it returns undefined value for **role**.
So it sops at line `role.relation('users').query().find({success: function(users)`
saying cannot call relation() for undefined value of role.

Comment: print role.. what that holds?

Comment: @venkat7668 undefined